# Custom Loader for endless scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, loader

I'm trying to create a custom loader which loads an list of data that works fine but now I want to added endless scrolling in the listview. I thought a logical place would be in the loader since almost all the examples I see on the interwebz have a private field in the custom loader which corresponds with the data to be returned to UI and in the deliverResult there is some code like this

```
@Override
public void deliverResult(T data) {
    T oldData = mData;
    mData = data;
    if (isStarted()) {
        // If the loader is currently started, we can immediately deliver a result
        super.deliverResult(mData);
    }
}
```

No I thought that mData still contains the previous list [1,2,3,4,5] cause the loader should cache the data to show it instantaneously on configuration changes. And data is the new list [6,7,8,9,10] for instance. I could just add data to mData, mData.add(data) and we are done. Don't have to repeat the code on multiple places or different adapters. But seemingly this doesn't work, everytime you call restartLoader to load the new data the framework creates a new instance of the Loader. Has anyone else run into this problem before? or should I just do the mData.add(data) in the Adapter or somewhere else in the code.

the full implementation of the custom loader which extends ApiResponseLoader which can also be find below:

```
public class SearchLoader extends ApiResponseLoader {

    private SearchType mSearchType;
    private int mOffset;
    private String mSearchQuery;


    public SearchLoader(Context context, SearchType type, int offset, String query) {
        super(context);
        mSearchType = type;
        mOffset = offset;
        mSearchQuery = query;
    }

    @Override
    public ApiResponse loadInBackground() {
        try {
            Map<String, String> parameters = Utils.parametersMap("q:" + mSearchQuery, "offset:" + String.valueOf(mOffset));
            return tryLoadInBackground(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            setError(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ApiResponse tryLoadInBackground(Map<String, String> parameters) throws Exception {
        if (mSearchQuery == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("mSearchQuery should not be null");
        }
        if (mSearchType == SearchType.A) {
            return RestAdapter().searchA(parameters);
        } else {
            return RestAdapter().searchB(parameters);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class ApiResponseLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ApiResponse> {
    private final static String TAG = ApiResponseLoader.class.getSimpleName();
    private ApiResponse mApiResponse;
    private Exception mError;

    public ApiResponseLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public abstract ApiResponse tryLoadInBackground(Map<String, String> parameters) throws Exception;

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (mApiResponse != null) {
            deliverResult(mApiResponse);
        }
        if (takeContentChanged() || mApiResponse == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onForceLoad() {
        super.onForceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(ApiResponse data) {
        // Attempt to cancel the current asynchronous load.
        super.onCanceled(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        // Ensure the loader has been stopped.
        onStopLoading();

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps' if needed
        if (mApiResponse != null) {
            mApiResponse = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(ApiResponse data) {
        if (isReset()) {
            // An async query came in while the loader is stopped. We don't need the result
            if (data != null) {
                onReleaseResources(data);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (mApiResponse != null) {
            mApiResponse.mMeta = data.mMeta;
            mApiResponse.mSampleList.addAll(data.mSampleList);
        } else {
            mApiResponse = data;
        }

        if (isStarted()) {
            // If the loader is currently started, we can immediately deliver a result
            super.deliverResult(mApiResponse);
        }
    }

    public Exception getError() {
        return mError;
    }

    public void setError(Exception mError) {
        this.mError = mError;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your definition of endless scrolling ?

Comment: when scrolling to the bottom loading more data. so in theory you don't reach the end of the list.

Comment: ok, i thought you mean data wrapping, that is circular data, what about to setup an adapter with initial blank data but with a right size and using the OnScrollListener to load the data on demand?

Comment: now the adapter gets initialized and we add the data ala Adapter.swap(Cursor). Bbut my question is if its possible to merge the old and the new data together in Loader instead of doing that in the view/adapter. This would simplify the code since we have a lot of data types and different rules for merging 2 list together, it would be more convenient of doing that in one place like in the Loader or in the adapter.

Comment: did you try a MergeCursor ?

Comment: your endless scrolling problem puzzled me a bit, thats why i created two simple gists: a chunked Cursor https://gist.github.com/pskink/52d7682b9d9643d7694e and test code https://gist.github.com/pskink/5b056b4501456dbf6629 of course you need to implement not fake AsyncRequest

Comment: pskink you do know that when you working with cursors its easier to just us the CursorLoader or if you want to add some custom functionality extend SimpleCursorLoader. And like I said in my previous comment I know you can do it in different ways.

Comment: i cannot see a case when you would need to extend SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up with just doing adapter.swap(dataset) and merged everything inside the adapter.